# AVplayer won't play audio from url in lockscreen or background

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsurlsession

I have a music app which downloads audio from an url and play it inside my app and background and everything works great. Now, I'm working on a feature where my app can play next song after current song is finished and my app works perfectly except when my device is in background or lockscreen. This is how to call AVPlayer to play audio from url.

```
guard let urlLink = googleDriveUrl else {return}
let urlReformatted = removePartOfGoogleDriveUrl(url: urlLink)
guard let url = URL(string: urlReformatted) else {return}
audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
audioPlayer?.play()
```

I couldn't figure out why then I use

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64,
```

to check downloading process with background fetch allowed and use the same audio url and found out that my app did download complete file even in background or lockscreen but AVPlayer won't play. It's so weird cause everything works great inside my app. Also, if I go back to the app from background and click play button, it plays the file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Project->Select Targets->Capabilities and set as below.
[image]

```
var backgroundIdentifier  =   UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
func configureBackgroundAudioTask() {
    backgroundIdentifier =  UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask (expirationHandler: { () -> Void in
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundIdentifier)
        self.backgroundIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    })
}
```

Comment: Do I need to implement anything beside that?

Comment: Tried and still AVPlayer won't response.

Comment: set background task session when AvPlayer configured for session.PLease check my edited answer

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, also because the memory is released much later on, my app often crashes due to an Out of Memory exception.